# There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'course'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, drop-down-menu, partial-views

i am getting a problem while populating data inside the dropdown...
I guess since i am using a partial view that is why it is creating problem.
Here's my code:

```
public ActionResult Register()
{
    var course = from Course c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Course))
                     select new { ID = c, Name = c.ToString() };
     ViewData["course"] = new SelectList(course, "ID", "Name");
     return view();
}

 public enum Course
{
    [Display(Name = "Basic Level", ShortName = "Basic")]
    Basic = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Intermidiate Level")]
    Intermidiate = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Advance Level")]
    Advance = 3
}
```

This is my Main view:

```
<table style="margin-top: 10px">
<tr>
    <td valign="top">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("LogOnPartial");}
    </td>
    <td width="20px">
    </td>
    <td align="left">
        @{Html.RenderPartial("CreatePartial");}
    </td>
</tr>
```

I have written this in my partial view(CreatePartial):

```
<td>
       @Html.DropDownList("course");
</td>
```

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. I am unable to reproduce the problem.

Model:

```
public enum Course
{
    [Display(Name = "Basic Level", ShortName = "Basic")]
    Basic = 1,

    [Display(Name = "Intermidiate Level")]
    Intermidiate = 2,

    [Display(Name = "Advance Level")]
    Advance = 3
}
```

Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var course = from Course c in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Course))
                     select new { ID = c, Name = c.ToString() };
        ViewData["course"] = new SelectList(course, "ID", "Name");
        return View();
    }
}
```

`Index.cshtml` view:

```
@{Html.RenderPartial("CreatePartial");}
```

`CreatePartial.cshtml` partial:

```
@Html.DropDownList("course")
```

I suspect that this is not working after you submit the form, not when it is initially loaded. And this might happen because you probably forgot to repopulate the `ViewData["course"]` in your `[HttpPost]` action and yet tried to redisplay the same view. If you want to redisplay the same view make sure that you fill the `ViewData["course"]` the same way you did in your GET action that was used to initially render the page.

Another thing to watch out is that you don't have some other `ViewData["course"]` value that is conflicting.

Comment: hi no such thing happening ya as u said i don have any post method..it is giving problem wen i load the page...

Comment: @user1274646, that's weird. Did you try my example? I have tested it in a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application and it worked fine.

Comment: hey i tried ur solution in a new proj its workin but the same soln i hav implemented in my proj and its nt workin...i m gettin the same error..please can u suggest me some other thing or jus rechk my code up if i hv made ny minor mistake